# On change event hide the textbox of selected row

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with a date column & action column. When I click on the row button, a text box is visible. On textbox change, I want to hide the text box & show the changed data `<span class="actual-date-label"><?=$item['actual_date']?></span>`

This is the code so far I have tried. But I am unable to hide textbox and show label on change event.

```
<tr data-id="<?=$item['product_id']?>">
    <td scope="col"><?=$item['planned_date']?></td>
    <td scope="col">
        <span class="actual-date-label"><?=$item['actual_date']?></span>
        <input
           type="text"
           size="8"
           class="form-control edit-datepicker"
           value="<?=$item['actual_date']?>"
           onchange="myFunction(this.value, <?=$item['p_id']?>)"
        >
    </td>
    <td scope="col" id="btn-edit"><input type="button" value="Edit"></td>
</tr>


    $(document).on('click', '#btn-edit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".edit-datepicker").show();
        $(this).closest("tr").find(".actual-date-label").hide();
    })
```

Comment: Can you work through the problem a bit: Does the click event listener get triggered? What's the value of `$(this)`? `$(this).closest("tr")`? `$(this).closest("tr").find ...`? Have you made sure that the elements are parsed in the DOM before this script is executed?

Comment: @j1mbl3s Yes when on click text box can be displayed. But after I make change in the text box I am not able to hide the textbox

Comment: The question doesn't really align with the code you've provided. You've provided code to show the input field and hide the label. Where's the code to do the opposite when the value has changed? Hint: the "blur" event may be helpful.

Comment: `Where's the code to do the opposite when the value has changed` I am not able to implement this stuff > `$(this).closest("tr").find(".edit-datepicker").css("display", "none");` I tried this but no effect

Comment: @j1mbl3s Ok FInally i solved by `    function myFunction(me, newDate, id) {
        me.find(".edit-datepicker").css("display", "none");
        me.find(".actual-date-label").css("display", "block");
        me.find(".actual-date-label").text(newDate);`